# change listview backgroung color at runtime

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview and used ArrayAddapter below is the code.

```
listviewUpload = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewUpload);
        arrlistTable = new ArrayList<String>();

        adptrtTable=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.custom_textbox_listview,
                arrlistTable);
```

Here i am updating this listview using AsynkTask. 
so as i am changing the dataset **"arrlistTable"**.
adding record one by one and notifying the  adapter.
Now here when i got the error in the result i am stopping the asynktask.
here at this position i want to change the color of the textview where i am getting the error. i am having the position of the textview where i am getting the error.

please help 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Samir its not the problem like we get at the force close. its like error in the data which we process so we are stopping the process. at that point we want to change the background of the text view

Answer (score 0):

Try handling onClick method for your view in getView() method in your custom adapter, something like this:

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {`

```
            TextView tv = (TextView)convertView;
            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                          tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                });

            return tv;
    }
```